# Convert array of 2-element arrays into a hash, where duplicate keys append additional values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

### For example

Given an array:

```
array = [[:a,:b],[:a,:c],[:c,:b]]
```

Return the following hash:

```
hash = { :a => [:b,:c] , :c => [:b] }
```

`hash = Hash[array]` overwrites previous associations, producing:

```
hash = { :a => :c , :c => :b }
```

Comment: Is this some flavour of homework? How do you intend to do this? Hashes aren't delimited with square brackets.

Comment: Have you tried using [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)?

Comment: Sorry - you're right about hashes, I'm still learning.  This isn't a flavour of homework, though it is a part of a solution I'm working on for a wider problem.  Our lecturer recommended SO for programming help.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Using functional baby steps:

```
irb:01.0> array = [[:a,:b],[:a,:c],[:c,:b]]
#=> [[:a, :b], [:a, :c], [:c, :b]]

irb:02.0> array.group_by(&:first)
#=> {:a=>[[:a, :b], [:a, :c]], :c=>[[:c, :b]]}

irb:03.0> array.group_by(&:first).map{ |k,a| [k,a.map(&:last)] }
#=> [[:a, [:b, :c]], [:c, [:b]]]

irb:04.0> Hash[ array.group_by(&:first).map{ |k,a| [k,a.map(&:last)] } ]
#=> {:a=>[:b, :c], :c=>[:b]}
```

Using imperative style programming:

```
irb:10.0> h = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k]=[] }
#=> {}

irb:11.0> array.each{ |k,v| h[k] << v }
#=> [[:a, :b], [:a, :c], [:c, :b]]

irb:12.0> h
#=> {:a=>[:b, :c], :c=>[:b]}
```

As an imperative one-liner:

```
irb:13.0> h = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k]=[] }.tap{ |h| array.each{ |k,v| h[k] << v } }
#=> {:a=>[:b, :c], :c=>[:b]}
```

Or using everyone's favorite `inject`:

```
irb:14.0> array.inject(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k]=[] }){ |h,(k,v)| h[k] << v; h }
#=> {:a=>[:b, :c], :c=>[:b]}
```

If you really want to have single values not collided as an array, you can either un-array them as a post-processing step, or use a different hash accumulation strategy that only creates an array upon collision. Alternatively, wrap your head around this:

```
irb:17.0> hashes = array.map{ |pair| Hash[*pair] } # merge many mini hashes
#=> [{:a=>:b}, {:a=>:c}, {:c=>:b}]

irb:18.0> hashes.inject{ |h1,h2| h1.merge(h2){ |*a| a[1,2] } }
#=> {:a=>[:b, :c], :c=>:b}
```

Answer (score 38):

**EDIT:** In Ruby 2.1+, you can use [Array#to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

```
pry(main)> [[:a,:b],[:a,:c],[:c,:b]].to_h
=> {:a=>:c, :c=>:b}
```

**END EDIT**

The public [] method on the Hash class accepts a key-value pair array and returns a hash with the first element of the array as key and the second as value.

The last value in the key-value pair will be the actual value when there are key duplicates.

```
Hash[[[:a,:b],[:a,:c],[:c,:b]]]
    => {:a=>:c, :c=>:b}
```

This syntax is valid in 1.9.3+ ; I'm not sure about earlier Ruby versions (it's not valid in 1.8.7)

ref: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D

Another interesting way of doing it would be using the inject method: (obviously the method above is more succinct and recommended for this specific problem)

```
[ [:a, :b], [:a, :c], [:c, :b] ].inject({}) { |memo, obj| 
   memo[obj.first] = obj.last
   memo 
}

=> {:a=>:c, :c=>:b}
```

inject iterates over the enumerable, your array in this case, starting with the injected parameter, in this case the empty hash {}.

For each object in the enumerable, the block is called with the variables memo and obj:

- obj is the current object in the array
- memo is the value that has been returned by your block's last iteration (for the first iteration, it's what you inject)

Comment: It's not the syntax that is wrong in 1.8.7, it's just that `Hash.[]` before 1.9 only accepted a flat list of k/v arguments, not a single array of key/value pairs. For 1.8 you had to do: `Hash[ *my_array.flatten ]`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @mkataja care to elaborate?

Comment: @Abdo sure. As far as I can see, the asker's specific problem was that "Hash[array] overwrites previous associations". Instead of `:a => :c` he wanted `:a => [:b,:c]`. Using `to_h` or `Hash[]` doesn't get you that.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done fairly succinctly using `each_with_object`.

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = (h[k] || []) + [v] }
```

Demonstrating in `irb`:

```
irb(main):002:0> array = [[:a,:b],[:a,:c],[:c,:b]]
=> [[:a, :b], [:a, :c], [:c, :b]]
irb(main):003:0> array.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = (h[k] || []) + [v] }
=> {:a=>[:b, :c], :c=>[:b]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of operations is very common in our project, so we added `to_group_h` to `Enumerable`. We can use it like:

```
[[:x, 1], [:x, 2], [:y, 3]].to_h
# => { x: 2, y: 3 }

[[:x, 1], [:x, 2], [:y, 3]].to_group_h
# => { x: [1, 2], y: [3] }
```

The following is the implementation of `Enumerable#to_group_h`:

```
module Enumerable
  if method_defined?(:to_group_h)
    warn 'Enumerable#to_group_h is defined'
  else
    def to_group_h
      hash = {}
      each do |key, value|
        hash[key] ||= []
        hash[key] << value
      end
      return hash
    end
  end
end
```