# How can I convert a 'long' table into a 'wide' table through an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, multidimensional-array, datatable

The thing I want to do is the following: I have a table built from an array.
Let's say:

```
_________
| a | b |
| c | d |
| e | f |
```

Now I want it 'converted' to:

```
_____________
| a | c | e |
| b | d | f |
```

#### Using:

Ruby: `1.9.3`
Rails: `3.2.8`

#### Goal:

```
a = [['a','b'],
     ['c','d'],
     ['e','f']]

array_for_table = conv_array_for_table a
=> [['a','c','e'],
    ['b','d','f']]
```

#### Research:

[Array Class Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html), but  I couldn't find anything about this here.

Thought I might have to do someting with array of hash or something..
[SO, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270972/convert-array-of-2-element-arrays-into-a-hash-where-duplicate-keys-append-addit)

> Given an array:
>   `array = [[:a,:b],[:a,:c],[:c,:b]]`
>
> Return the following hash:
>   `hash = { [:a => [:b,:c]] , [:c => :b] }`
>
> Hash[array] overwrites previous associations, producing:
>   `hash = { [:a => :c] , [:c => :b] }`

#### Self thinking without positive result

Maybe I should be doing something with hashes?

```
1.9.3p194 :018 > def conv_array a=[]  
1.9.3p194 :019?>   conv_a = []  
1.9.3p194 :020?>   a.each do |k,v|  
1.9.3p194 :021 >       conv_a.push(k)  
1.9.3p194 :022?>   end  
1.9.3p194 :023?>   a.each do |k,v|
1.9.3p194 :024 >       conv_a.push(v)
1.9.3p194 :025?>   end
1.9.3p194 :026?> end
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is matrix transposition.. take a look here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-transpose

so basically all you have to do is call:

```
a.transpose()
```

or even shorter:

```
a.t
```

Comment: You're my hero. This is exactly what I was looking for!