# How could I group by time(HH:MM) with mongoid or ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

How could I group by time(HH:MM) with mongoid or ruby

I want to group by the following data by `departure_at`(HH:MM).

How to get it easier with Rails or Mongoid

Expect result:

```
{ 
    '06:40': [item125, item131],
    '10:20': [item126],
    ....
```

## query result by mongoid

```
[125] #<Tiger _id: 811_0640_1010_TPE_KIX,  to: "KIX", from: "TPE", price: 4899,departure_at: 08-11 06:40:00 UTC>,
[126] #<Tiger _id: 811_1020_0305_TPE_KIX,  to: "KIX", from: "TPE", price: 5450,departure_at: 08-11 10:20:00 UTC>,
....
[131] #<Tiger _id: 812_0640_1010_TPE_KIX,  to: "KIX", from: "TPE", price: 4899,departure_at: 08-12 06:40:00 UTC>,
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make an array of `["HH:MM", object]`. Then you can use the trick from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270972/convert-array-of-2-element-arrays-into-a-hash-where-duplicate-keys-append-addit)

```
array = @your_objects.map{|obj| [obj.date_departure.strftime("%H:%m"), obj]} 
Hash[ array.group_by(&:first).map{ |k,a| [k,a.map(&:last)] } ]
```