# How to convert, in Ruby, a list of key value pairs to a Hash, such that values with duplicate keys are stored in an array?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, key-value

Given a list key-value pairs, in the form of an array of arrays - e.g. `[ ["key1","value1"], ["key2","value2"], ["key1", "value3"] ]`, how to convert these to a Hash that stores all the values, in the most elegant way?

For the above example, I would want to get `{ "key1" => [ "value1", "value3" ], "key2" => [ "value2" ] }`.

Comment: This question has already been

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270972/convert-array-of-2-element-arrays-into-a-hash-where-duplicate-keys-append-addit

Comment: I didn't find it when I went looking, and that question isn't exactly what I need - though the approved answer has what I need and if I'd seen it before then I wouldn't have asked the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are in both hashes being merged.

```
arr = [ ["key1","value1"], ["key2","value2"], ["key1", "value3"] ]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h.update(k=>[v]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {"key1"=>["value1", "value3"], "key2"=>["value2"]}
```

Comment: Or, using a semantic I'm more familiar with: `arr.inject({}) { |h,(k,v)|  h.merge!(k=>[v]) { |k,o,n| o+n } }`. Although @sawa's answer was first, I like this solution better as it has less moving parts and is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
[["key1","value1"], ["key2","value2"], ["key1", "value3"]]
.group_by(&:first).each{|_, v| v.map!(&:last)}
```

Comment: Sorry for un-accepting your answer - it was good, did fit the parameters and was earlier, but I think @Cary's answer is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k]=[] }.tap{ |h| array.each{ |k,v| h[k] << v } }
```

OR

```
c = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
array.each{|k, v| c[k] << v}
```

Comment: That is indeed an improvement, though the array is generated by another process and I was kind of hoping to keep this little bitty "functional" - i.e. `kvlist -> dictionary -> operate on dictionary`.

Comment: @Guss I didn't get you

Comment: Something more like @sawa that does this in one line and the result can be used by adding another expression.

Answer (score -1):

My best solution so far is this:

```
kvlist.inject(Hash.new([])) do |memo,a| 
  memo[a[0]] = (memo[a[0]] << a[1])
  memo
end
```

Which I think is not very good.

Comment: [Use a block](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new). Right now that hash is returning one and the same array for non-existent keys. See @test's answer.

Comment: So, something like `kvlist.inject(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |h,a| h[a0] << a[1]; h; }` ?