# Populate missing entries when comparing arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three arrays of dates with counts:

```
first = [["July 01", "2"]["July 03", "2"]]
second = [["June 30", "2"]["July 01", "2"]["July 02", "2"]]
third = [["July 01", "2"]["July 02", "2"]]
```

I am trying (without success) to compare the three arrays, get the full range of dates, and inject the missing ones with 0 results into the others... So that in the end each array will have entries for dates starting on June 30 until July 3, like so:

```
first = [["June 30", "0"]["July 01", "2"]["July 02", "0"]["July 03", "2"]]
second = [["June 30", "2"]["July 01", "2"]["July 02", "2"]["July 03", "0"]]
third = [["June 30", "0"]["July 01", "2"]["July 02", "2"]["July 03", "0"]]
```

I tried a bunch of really complex comparisons (like doing deduction, storing as a new array, then using that array to add to the missing ones, but it gets really complex when there are more than two arrays to compare) and injection to do this but I think there must be a relatively simple way to do this with Ruby or Rails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way, using `Date`:

```
require 'date'

def compare_dates(*items)
  all_dates = items.flatten(1).map { |d| Date.parse(d.first) }
  str_dates = (all_dates.min..all_dates.max).map { |d| d.strftime("%B %d") }

  items.map do |arr|
    str_dates.map do |date|
      current = arr.select { |e| e[0] == date }.flatten
      current.empty? ? [date, "0"] : current
    end
  end
end

compare_dates(first, second, third)
#=> [[["June 30", "0"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "0"], ["July 03", "2"]],
#    [["June 30", "2"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "2"], ["July 03", "0"]],
#    [["June 30", "0"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "2"], ["July 03", "0"]]]
```

If you want to overwrite the values of each array, you could do this:

```
first, second, third = compare_dates(first, second, third)

first
#=> [["June 30", "0"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "0"], ["July 03", "2"]]

second
#=> [["June 30", "2"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "2"], ["July 03", "0"]]

third
#=> [["June 30", "0"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "2"], ["July 03", "0"]]
```

Comment: Clean, concise, beautiful. Thank you Gerry.

Answer (score 1):

I have one question why is this an array of arrays? If you can make this into a hash, the problem is very simple to handle. It can look something like this:

```
first = {"july 01" => 2, "july 02" => 1}
second = {"june 31" => 1, "july 01" => 1}


keys = first.keys
keys << second.keys

keys.each do |key|
  first[key] = first[key] || 0
end
```

I have not tested this and this might not be the most efficient way, but you can optimize on top of this. I hope that helps.

You can also use something like this [Convert array of 2-element arrays into a hash, where duplicate keys append additional values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270972/convert-array-of-2-element-arrays-into-a-hash-where-duplicate-keys-append-addit) to convert it into a Hash.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really help. I already wrote something that can handle two arrays (or hashes, doesn't matter). I need a method that will compare three or more arrays and return the desired result, without being too complex. I think I may be missing a core ruby method to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the union of all arrays then calculate from it.

```
all = first | second | third
 #=> [["July 01", "2"], ["July 03", "2"], ["June 30", "2"], ["July 02", "2"]]

(first | all).map { |k, v| first.include?([k, v]) ? [k, v] : [k, "0"] }
             .sort_by { |i| [ Time.new(0, i[0][0..2]).month, i[0][-2..-1] ] }

 #=> [["June 30", "0"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "0"], ["July 03", "2"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [[["July 01", "2"], ["July 03", "2"]],
       [["June 30", "2"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "2"]],
       [["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "2"]]]

require 'date'

default = arr.flatten(1).
              map(&:first).
              uniq.
              sort_by { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%B %d') }.
              product(['0']).
              to_h
  #=> {"June 30"=>"0", "July 01"=>"0", "July 02"=>"0", "July 03"=>"0"}

arr.map { |a| default.merge(a.to_h).to_a }
  #=> [[["June 30", "0"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "0"], ["July 03", "2"]],
  #    [["June 30", "2"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "2"], ["July 03", "0"]],
  #    [["June 30", "0"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "2"], ["July 03", "0"]]]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
b = arr.flatten(1)
  #=> [["July 01", "2"], ["July 03", "2"], ["June 30", "2"], ["July 01", "2"],
  #    ["July 02", "2"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "2"]]
c = b.map(&:first)
  #=> ["July 01", "July 03", "June 30", "July 01", "July 02", "July 01", "July 02"]
d = c.uniq
  #=> ["July 01", "July 03", "June 30", "July 02"]
e = d.sort_by { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%B %d') }
  #=> ["June 30", "July 01", "July 02", "July 03"] 
f = e.product(['0'])
  #=> [["June 30", "0"], ["July 01", "0"], ["July 02", "0"], ["July 03", "0"]]
default = f.to_h
  #=> {"June 30"=>"0", "July 01"=>"0", "July 02"=>"0", "July 03"=>"0"}
```

To compute

```
arr.map { |a| default.merge(a.to_h).to_a }
```

the first value of `arr` is passed to the block and the block variable `a` is set equal to that value and the block calculation is performed.

```
  a = arr.first
    #=> [["July 01", "2"], ["July 03", "2"]]
  g = a.to_h
    #=> {"July 01"=>"2", "July 03"=>"2"}
  h = default.merge(g)
    #=> {"June 30"=>"0", "July 01"=>"2", "July 02"=>"0", "July 03"=>"2"}
  h.to_a
    #=> [["June 30", "0"], ["July 01", "2"], ["July 02", "0"], ["July 03", "2"]]
```

The calculations for the other values of `arr` are similar.

For the calculation of `d` see [Date::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime).