# How to pluck multiple attributes in Rails 3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

and need to get a hash mapping `Person`'s `id`s to their `name`s:

```
{1 => "Paul", 2 => "Aliyah", 3 => ... }
```

Now, the obvious way would be

```
Person.all.collect { |p| [p.id, p.name] }.to_h
```

However, I don't need to instantiate every `Person`, I just need the hash. In Rails 4, I can `.pluck(:id, :name)` instead of `collect`, however in 3.x, `pluck` takes only one argument. However I found this workaround to get what I want without loading the models:

```
Person.all.group(:id).minimum(:name)
```

**Question:** will I burn in hell? Also, is there a more elegant way to do this, and are there any drawbacks of this hacky approach that I may not be aware of? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pretty good write up of this situation and various tactics for handling it: [Plucking Multiple Columns in Rails 3](http://meltingice.net/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/)

My preference of suggested solutions there is to make and include a module:

```
# multi_pluck.rb
require 'active_support/concern'

module MultiPluck
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.pluck_all(relation, *args)
      connection.select_all(relation.select(args))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  def self.pluck_id_and_name
     result = connection.select_all(select(:id, :name))
     if result.any?
       # if you are using Ruby 2.1+
       result.to_h
       # Works in 1.9.3+
       Hash[result]
     end
  end
end
```

Since the result should be an array of arrays we can use nifty trick to get a hash with the first element as keys and the second as values:

```
Hash[ [ [1, "Joe"], [2, "Jill"] ] ] 
# => { 1 => "Joe", 2 => "Jill"}
```

See:

- [Convert array of 2-element arrays into a hash, where duplicate keys append additional values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270972/convert-array-of-2-element-arrays-into-a-hash-where-duplicate-keys-append-addit)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid loading all of the objects you could do this:

```
hash = Hash.new
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT id, name FROM persons").each {|person| hash[person['id'].to_s] = person['name'].to_s}
```

Answer (score 0):

My company used one of the tactics from [Plucking Multiple Columns in Rails 3](http://meltingice.net/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/) before.
But we had trouble upgrading from Rails 3 to Rails 4 because it didn't work in Rails 4.

I suggest using [pluck_all](https://github.com/khiav223577/pluck_all) gem which has high test coverage in Rails 3, 4, 5, so you will not worry about future upgrades.